# Arithmetic on a Series in Pandas DF With Conditional - Prior Operation Gets Overwritten

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements

I'm scraping some salary data that I need to convert to either and hourly or annual rate based on another column. I've researched how to do this - which probably isn't the most efficient - but it works for one line.

Data

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

columns = ['Location','Hourly','Annually','Monthly','Daily','Average','Hourly_Rate','Annual_Rate']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
df.loc[1] = ['A',True,False,False,False,10.10,np.nan,np.nan]
df.loc[2] = ['B',False,True,False,False,50000,np.nan,np.nan]

df['Annual_Rate'] = (df['Average'] * 2080).where(df['Hourly'] == True) #need this line to run and not get overwritten
df['Annual_Rate'] = df['Average'].where(df['Annually'] == True ) #overwrites prior line
df['Annual_Rate'] = df['Average'].where(df['Annually'] == True & pd.isna(df['Annual_Rate'])) #overwrites prior line and is incorrect

df['Hourly_Rate'] = (df['Average'] / 2080).where([(df['Annually'] == True) & (pd.isnull(df['Hourly_Rate']))])
df['Hourly_Rate'] = df['Average'].where(df['Hourly'] == True & (pd.isna(df['Hourly_Rate'])))
df['Hourly_Rate'] = df['Average'].where(df['Hourly'] == True)
df.head(10)
```

These are the lines that should be/I need to work:

```
df['Hourly_Rate'] = (df['Average'] / 2080).where([(df['Annually'] == True) & (pd.isnull(df['Hourly_Rate']))])
df['Annual_Rate'] = (df['Average'] * 2080).where(df['Hourly'] == True)
```

Desired Outcome:

```
+---+----------+--------+----------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+-------------+
|   | Location | Hourly | Annually | Monthly | Daily | Average | Hourly_Rate | Annual_Rate |
+---+----------+--------+----------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+-------------+
| 1 | A        | TRUE   | FALSE    | FALSE   | FALSE |    10.1 |        10.1 |       21008 |
| 2 | B        | FALSE  | TRUE     | FALSE   | FALSE |   50000 | 24.03846154 |       50000 |
+---+----------+--------+----------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what you expect as your desired output?

Comment: Yep - sorry about that - added the two columns/values I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.Series.where` doesn't work the same as `numpy.where`. The latter can be used to specify a vectorised if-else condition and is likely what you need:

```
df['Annual_Rate'] = np.where(df['Hourly'], df['Average'] * 2080, df['Average'])

df['Hourly_Rate'] = np.where(df['Annually'] & df['Hourly_Rate'].isnull(),
                             df['Average'] / 2080, df['Average'])
```

`pd.Series.where` updates a series with a given value where the condition is *not* met, otherwise remains unchanged (in this case `NaN` when not specified), as noted in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

> Return an object of same shape as self and whose corresponding entries
>   are from self where cond is `True` and otherwise are from *other*.

Also note you can use Boolean series directly rather than testing `df[col] == True`.

Comment: Ok great thank you - I'm just implementing it now to check - and thanks for the otherwise direction, checking why it doesn't work in my script - and thanks for the Boolean note as well.